# Using printf with bash. printed strings overflowing columns

Tags: string, bash

I'm using Bash. I am using `printf "%-40s%s" $a $b` to display two strings in two columns. The second string is very long and is overflowing and printing at the beginning of the next line in the first column. How can I make the string in the second column overflow into the second column?

Comment: It does produce like it.

Comment: I didn't make the question clear. There were two strings in two columns. First string was left aligned. Second string was at column 40. Second string was long and overflowed into next line. But it overflowed in to the first column but did not overflow into the second column which is what I wanted. How can I make it do that?

Comment: How are you deciding where to wrap the second column?

Comment: The overflow seems to be related to window size. If the window is smaller than the length of the string being displayed in the second column, when the printf command is executed it overflows into the beginning of the next line rather than the second column. I assume that nothing can be done about that? I am using the Cygwin terminal. Perhaps I need to preset the window size to prevent it happening. It is reproducable using the formatting string I gave

Comment: Is your window 70 columns wide? What does `tput cols` say? Does the end of the string really overwrite the contents of the first column on the same line? Also those three example lines above are three different lengths which isn't helping anything here.

Comment: Window is 70 columns wide. tput not supported on cygwin. Sorry about example agreed it is not very helpful but I'm new to this sort of forum. I have put 40 a's in the first string With second string of 50b's. When I execute the command with the format string as in the example 10 b's overflow into the next line in the first column (sorry not the same line, as in example) rather than in the second column. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not pretty and I still feel like it could be better (but I don't see any obvious ways of making it better) but it works (thought doesn't have correct alignment for the first column) for me:

col.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=$1
b=$2
w=${3:-$(tput cols)}


fmta=$(fold -w 40 <<<"$a")
lca=$(wc -l <<<"$fmta")

fmtb=$(fold -w $(( w - 40 )) <<<"$b")
lcb=$(wc -l <<<"$fmtb")

if [ "$lca" -lt "$lcb" ]; then
    fmta+=$(printf ' \n%.0s' $(seq 0 $(( lcb - lca ))))
fi

pr -t -2 <<<"$fmta"$'\n'"$fmtb"
```

Run as:

```
$ a=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
$ b=bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
$ ./col.sh "$a" "$b"
```

Takes a third optional argument for terminal width for when `$(tput cols)` doesn't work. Can probably use `./col.sh "$a" "$b" "$COLUMNS"`.

Comment: Great. Works well for me. I'll put that in a function. Only problem is that there doesn't seem any way to fix the window size when the original shell script runs so that the w variable (i.e. in the absence of tput) can be set.

Comment: @phil Without `tput` and without `$COLUMNS` (from the terminal/shell) I'm not sure how else to get the width of the window. You should have `$COLUMNS` set in your session so you might just be able to export it and have that work where you call `col.sh` (or embed that in the `col.sh` directly). But beyond that (or passing `$COLUMNS` through somehow I'm not sure what else you can do. Sorry.

Comment: $COLUMNS as third argument worked fine. I'm OK now. Brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
printf "%40s\n%40s\n" "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
             aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
             bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

`-` before `40` is for left alignment.

Comment: I didn't make the question clear. There were two strings in two columns. First string was left aligned. Second string was at column 40. Second string was long and overflowed into next line. But it overflowed in to the first column but did not overflow into the second column which is what I wanted. How can I make it do that?

Comment: Can you just echo both string and paste their values. It will be easier for me to understand then.

Comment: The overflow seems to be related to window size. If the window is smaller than the length of the string being displayed in the second column, when the printf command is executed it overflows into the beginning of the next line rather than the second column. I assume that nothing can be done about that? I am using the Cygwin terminal. Perhaps I need to preset the window size to prevent it happening. It is reproducable using the formatting string I gave.